# Perform some action depending upon the text in the inbox of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4

I am having a message in iPhone inbox. I want to send that message to a small app which in my iPhone to do some particular task.

Can some one suggest me , Whether it is possible to send that SMS to our application development.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately.

Comment: Big no untill its not a jailbroken phone..

Comment: can you explain some more ,what do you need to do task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately is not possible handle sms at SDK level.
If you manage the send of sms you can add a link into it and, using a custom url scheme, passing data to your app.

Comment: Giordano Scalzo how can i restart my apps via sms link ,please can you give me tutorial or example .how to handle this kind of issue.thanks.

Comment: This is a easy tutorial:
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: Btw, I used wrong words: it,s not possible restart an app already running, but you can start it or passing data through a link pressed.